# Как поменять src картинки(элемента img) при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть изображения:

```
<div class="swiper-slide"><img  class="gallary__image" src="img/darkSlider.png" alt=""></div>
и
<div class="swiper-slide"><img  class="gallary__image" src="img/kightSlider.png" alt=""></div>
```

Нужно при клике на кнопку

```
            <div class="btn" >
                <div class="btn__indicator">
                    <div class="btn__icon-container">
                        <i class="btn__icon fa-solid"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Что бы менялось значение **src** из **darkSlider** в **lightSlider** и наоборот и чтоб значения сохранялось при перезагрузки странице.

Comment: И что у вас не получается?

Comment: не знаю как сделать

Comment: Покажите, что делали и что не получается? + localStorage для хранения изменений при перезагрузке.

Comment: Дело в том, что учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Ожидая, что по селектору найдется всего 2 элемента, смену картинок при клике можно сделать так:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn__icon');
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.gallary__image');
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  [imgs[0].src, imgs[1].src] = [imgs[1].src, imgs[0].src];
  //localStorage.setItem('img', JSON.stringify([imgs[0].src, imgs[1].src]));
})

function load() {
  //const stor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('img') || null);
  //if (stor) {
  //  [imgs[0].src, imgs[1].src] = [stor[0], stor[1]];
  //}
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
  <div class="swiper-slide"><img width="100" class="gallary__image" src="https://imgholder.ru/100%D1%85100/222222/ddddd&text=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F&font=arial" alt=""></div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"><img width="100" class="gallary__image" src="https://imgholder.ru/100%D1%85100/dddddd/222222&text=%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F&font=arial" alt=""></div>
  <br />
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="btn__indicator">
      <div class="btn__icon-container">
        <i class="btn__icon fa-solid">Кнопка смены картинки</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

> Закомментированный код надо раскомментировать, что бы работало локальное хранилище

Comment: почему-то не работает(

Comment: @odium Запустите пример выше, все работает. Что именно у вас не работает? Возможно, что то не так перенесли в свой код?